# Physical Interpretation of Diagonal Green's Function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, greens-functions, propagator

In the context of one-particle non-relativstic quantum mechanics, let $H$ be the Hamiltonian for the system and let $z\in\mathbb{C}$ be given.

What is the physical meaning of the following object:
$$ \left|\langle x|\left(H-z\right)^{-1}|x\rangle \right|$$

Apparently it is a transition probability, so it should correspond to some sort of probability of going from one state to another?

Intuitively I feel like it should somehow correspond to the number of times the particle revisits the point $x$, or the likelihood for that to happen?

Any formal answer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This looks interesting. Could you give some context? Where did you encounter this expression?

Comment: If you look at Stone's formula for computing the spectral measures of $H$, you get to matrix elements of the resolvent. Then to show that these spectral measures are bounded (as $\Im{z}\to0$) you sometimes start with showing that the diagonal matrix element is bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is one physical problem where this quantity appears directly. Consider the Schrodinger equation with a delta-functional source of a particle at $x=x_0$, $t=t_0$:
$$
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi=H\psi+\delta(x-x_0)\delta(t-t_0).\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad(1)
$$
As known, its solution can be expressed through the Green function:
$$
\psi(x,t)=\langle x|G(t-t_0)|x_0\rangle,
$$
where 
$$
G(E)=(E-H)^{-1},\qquad G(t)=\int\frac{dE}{2\pi}\,G(E)e^{-iE t}.
$$
Now introduce the source of wave of frequency $\omega$ at the point $x_0$:
$$
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi=H\psi+\delta(x-x_0)e^{-i\omega t}.\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad (3)
$$
Noting that $e^{-i\omega t}=\int dt_0\:e^{-i\omega t_0}\delta(t-t_0)$, we get the superposition of previous solutions:
$$
\psi(x,t)=\int dt_0\:\langle x|G(t-t_0)|x_0\rangle e^{-i\omega t_0}=\{t-t_0=\tau\}=e^{-i\omega t}\int d\tau\:\langle x|G(\tau)|x_0\rangle e^{i\omega\tau}.
$$
Now look at your formula:
$$
\left\langle x\left|\frac1{H-z}\right|x\right\rangle=-G(z)=-\int d\tau\:\langle x|G(\tau)|x\rangle e^{iz\tau}.
$$
Comparing the formulas, we get
$$
\psi(x_0,t)=-e^{-i\omega t}\left\langle x_0\left|\frac1{H-\omega}\right|x_0\right\rangle.
$$
Thus the answer is: *if we have a source of quantum wave of a frequency $z$ and unit amplitude at the point $x$ then $|\langle x|(H-z)^{-1}|x\rangle|$ would be the full amplitude of quantum wave at the same point $x$*. As concerns complex values of $z$, we need to be cautious with causality of the Green function (I ignored this issue here).

Maybe another formula can be helpful: given stationary states of the Hamiltonian $H|\varphi_i\rangle=E_i|\varphi_i\rangle$, we can relate
$$
\left\langle x\left|\frac1{H-z}\right|x\right\rangle=\sum_i\frac{|\varphi_i(x)|^2}{E_i-z}
$$
to the local density of states
$$
D(E,x)=\langle x|\delta(E-H)|x\rangle=\sum_i\delta(E-E_i)|\varphi_i(x)|^2
$$
in the following way:
$$
\left\langle x\left|\frac1{H-z}\right|x\right\rangle=\int dE\:\frac{D(E,x)}{E-z}.
$$
At every $z=E_i$ the function $\langle x|(H-z)^{-1}|x\rangle$ has the pole of the residue $|\varphi_i(x)|^2$.

**UPDATE**
Physical interpretation of the Schrodinger equation (1) with a source term $\propto\delta(t-t_0)$ is the following. Consider
$$
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}|\psi\rangle=H|\psi\rangle+\delta(t-t_0)|\psi_0\rangle,\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad(2)
$$
where $|\psi\rangle$ is expanded in the eigenvectors of the Hamiltonian:
$$
|\psi\rangle=\sum_ic_i|\varphi_i\rangle,\qquad H|\varphi_i\rangle=E_i|\varphi_i\rangle.
$$
Then for each coefficient $c_i(t)$ we get
$$
i\frac{dc_i}{dt}=E_ic_i+\delta(t-t_0)\langle\varphi_i|\psi_0\rangle.
$$
Using the initial condition $c_i(-\infty)=0$, we have
$$
c_i(t)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}0,&t<t_0,\\
-i\langle\varphi_i|\psi_0\rangle e^{-iE_i(t-t_0)},&t>t_0.\end{array}\right.
$$
The same solution (except the phase factor) can be obtained from the following equation for $c_i(t)$ without the source term, but with nontrivial initial condition:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}i\frac{dc_i}{dt}=E_ic_i,\\
c_i(t_0)=\langle\varphi_i|\psi_0\rangle.\end{array}\right.\quad\Rightarrow\qquad c_i(t)=\langle\varphi_i|\psi_0\rangle e^{-iE_i(t-t_0)}.
$$
*Thus the Schrodinger equation (2) with the source term $\delta(t-t_0)|\psi_0\rangle$ is equivalent to that without source term, but with initial condition $|\psi(t_0)\rangle=-i|\psi_0\rangle$. In particular, Eq. (1) describes wave function propagation beginning from the state $\psi(x_0,t_0)=-i\delta(x-x_0)$, i.e. it is the Green function (up to a phase).*

**Now about oscillating source term in Eq. (3).** Unfortunately, it cannot be interpreted as an initial condition for $\psi$, but we can consider the system if two coupled equations
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{l}i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi_1=H_1\psi_1+\lambda\psi_2,\\i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\psi_2=H_2\psi_2+\lambda\psi_1,\end{array}\right.
$$
which can describe physically a motion of a particle in two regions of space $R_1$, $R_2$, where
$$
\psi(\mathbf{r},t)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\psi_1(\mathbf{r},t),&\mathbf{r}\in R_1,\\
\psi_2(\mathbf{r},t),&\mathbf{r}\in R_2,\end{array}\right.
\qquad H(\mathbf{r})=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}H_1(\mathbf{r}),&\mathbf{r}\in R_1,\\
H_2(\mathbf{r}),&\mathbf{r}\in R_2.\end{array}\right.
$$
The small coupling term $\lambda$ can be responsible for a tunneling between the two regions. So the term $\lambda\psi_2$ acts as a wave function source for a subsystem 1. See the example on the picture: an electron with the energy $\omega$ enters the nanostructure (subsystem 1) from the tip (subsystem 2) at the point $x_0$. It creates the source term $\propto \delta(x-x_0)e^{-i\omega t}$ in the Schrodinger equation for subsystem 1.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. However, there are two things I don't understand: (1) regarding the first alternative, what does the Schroedinger equation with a source mean physically? I've never encountered that. I guess you could put the delta function it in the potential? (2) In the second alternative, you've expressed the object I'm inquiring about using the density of states, but what does it then say about the object I'm inquiring about, physically?

Comment: @PPR (1) See the update, I hope it will be helpful. (2) I don't really know what can we say about the absolute value |\rangle x|(H-z)^{-1}|x\rangle|, but, clearly, it is peaked near $z=E_i$.